# Bind h:selectBooleanCheckbox value to int/Integer instead of boolean/Boolean

Tags: jsf, checkbox, int, boolean, converters

I have a `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{someBean.prop}">` where `prop` is a property of type `int`. Is it really not working straight away? Do I have to implement a custom converter to convert `Boolean` to `int`? Does anyone happen to have converter code for that at stock? I read that there is some bug in JSF 2.0 that prevents converters for `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` to be processed. Can anyone confirm that?

I use MyFaces 2, Tomahawk and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` should, as its name say, be bound to a `boolean` or `Boolean` property. Nothing else. That it allows a `converter` attribute is actually a [bug in the spec](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/460). It should never have allowed it.

The problem is more in your model, why would you use an `int` to represent a boolean state? Change your model to let it be a fullworthy `boolean`.

If changing the model isn't an option for some reason (a 3rd party API, a stupid architect, or stupid business restrictions, etc), then wrap the model getter/setter in the backing bean like follows

```
public boolean isChecked() {
    return someModel.getSomeInt() != 0;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    someModel.setSomeInt(checked ? 1 : 0);
}
```

and use it instead as `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked}" />`.

Comment: Thank you! I will use the wrapper method, since the model is not mine.

Comment: Could be considered as spam, but Balus I love you. I've got the same problem and provided a custom converter, which isn't triggered. Saved me tons of time. Thanks!

Comment: @asrijaal: you're more than welcome, but sorry I am already married.

Comment: How to warp two values?

Answer (score 2):

just to say MySQL doesn't have boolean as field type choice, and it could be an example for this need.

Comment: I'd just solve it in the persistence/model side rather than business side. If JDBC, do for example `model.setSomeBoolean(resultSet.getInt(columnname) != 0)` and so on. If JPA a custom mapping type can be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can set field as `tinyint` in MySQL. Actually problem is getting method name when you create a boolean variable. Use method name `getChecked()` instead of `isChecked()`.