# Boolean to custom string converter in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, converters

I have a requirement that all boolean fields should be saved in database as "Y" and "F" values. In my form I'm using primefaces `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` for retrieving boolean input:

```
<h:outputLabel for="termsOfUseAck" value="#{msg['user_sign_up.terms_of_use_ack']}" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="termsOfUseAck" value="#{accountRegistrationController.account.termsOfUseAck}" converter="booleanToYNConverter" />
```

and my converter is defined as follows:

```
@FacesConverter(value="booleanToYNConverter")
public class BooleanToYNConverter implements Converter {
    public BooleanToYNConverter() {
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext,
                              UIComponent uiComponent,
                              String param) {
        try {
            Boolean result = Boolean.parseBoolean(param);
            System.out.println("#BooleanToYNConverter.getAsObject param is: " + param);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(exception);
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext,
                              UIComponent uiComponent,
                              Object obj) {
        try {
            if ((obj != null) && ((Boolean) obj)) {
                System.out.println("#BooleanToYNConverter.getAsString returns Y");
                return "Y";
            } else {
                System.out.println("#BooleanToYNConverter.getAsString returns N");
                return "N";
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

In console I can see that converter is called and it returns single character:

```
#BooleanToYNConverter.getAsString returns Y
```

But unfortunately in the end `accountRegistrationController.account.termsOfUseAck` is set to `true` or `false` values instead of desired `Y` or `N`. What am I doing wroing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706513/jsf-selectbooleancheckbox-with-int-type/5707455#5707455

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I ask if using wrapper on getter and setter is my only option here? That was my first idea but I thought that converters are more elegant and easy to maintain way.

Comment: The easiest way is to set Y or N based on true false by doing,  entity.setColumn(termsOfUseAck?"Y":"N").

Answer (score 1):

I began writing a comment, but realized my opinion could be written in a whole answer. First of all, using `String` values for pure sets of values as you're doing does not make sense. That's what [enum types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are for. Both JSF 2 and most popular ORMs as Hibernate support them, so for your case the ideal thing would be something like that:

```
public enum Option {
    Y, N;
}
```

Well, having said that, it doesn't make any sense to store boolean values in a set, so you need to analyze your model more deeply.

If there's an attribute with just two possibilities use boolean, as it normally takes a single bit in the DB layer. If, in contrary, it's a whole set of possibilities (which could also increase in the future), then go with an `enum`, in your control code and also in the DB or whatever you use for persistency.

Comment: Some DBMS like MySQL/MariaDB connectors will persist it as `tinyint(1)` and `1` means `true` and `0` means `false`. This means the questioner should really re-analyze his data model. Common is: `private Boolean someFlag;` with getter/setter and then represent it in the application layer as *Yes* and *No*.