# Checkbox callback and persistance

Tags: java, checkbox, primefaces

I am trying to persist checkbox of a datatable item.

In simple terms, I need to persist this checkbox. Once it is checked, it needs to stay checked until it is unchecked via GUI.

```
               <p:column width="20">
              <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{datas.data_checkbox}" onchange="selectme(#{indexvar});">
                  <p:ajax event="change"
                            async="true"
                            process="@form"
                            global="true"
                            update="data_tab"
                            listener="#{datasBean.updateDataProcess}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{datas}" target="#{datasBean.selectedData}"/>
                    </p:ajax>
               </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </p:column>


 public void updateDataProcess() {
    try {
    System.out.println("Update process is in progress...");

    if (selectedData.getData_process() == "true") {
        System.out.println("Process value is true");
        dataAccessObject.updateDataProcess(selectedData.getData_pk(),"1" );
    }
    if (selectedData.getData_process() == "false") {
        System.out.println("Process value is true");
        dataAccessObject.updateDataProcess(selectedData.getData_pk(),"0" );
    } 
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

    public Integer updateDataProcess(String data_pk, String data_process) throws SocketTimeoutException {
    try {
        //&setDataStatus=true&dataPk=2&dataStatus=2
        String updateDataProcessUrl = urlconstants.data_api_url + "/data.jsp?mrs_rest=true"
                + "&setDataProcess=true"
                + "&dataPk=" + data_pk
                + "&dataProcess=" + data_process;

        System.out.println("json_call=" + updateDataProcessUrl);
        return Integer.parseInt(tools.getJSON(updateDataProcessUrl, 5000).trim());


    } catch (JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have a JSON utility which can write integer to a data column in the database as well.

I am not sure if the checkbox callback is expecting boolean or not.

If it is, do I need to convert the boolean to integer and vice versa?

I do not seem to be able to persist this type of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706513/bind-hselectbooleancheckbox-value-to-int-integer-instead-of-boolean-boolean

Answer (score 0):

The value of the checkbox needs to be boolean.

I defined boolean datatyped property in my setters and getters.

Created a column in postgres to boolean data type as well.